Lie-Group Structure of the Pin and Spin group.
I understand the algebraic properties of the groups Pin and Spin but I was wondering why they were Lie-Groups. I came across this question: Lie group structure of the spin group
Where it is explained that it suffices to show that Pin is closed as a subgroup of the group of invertible elements of a Clifford algebra (over an appropriate field that induces the topology).
Let $Cl$ be the Clifford algebra corresponding to a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{K}$. In the answer it is suggested that Pin is closed as it is the kernel of the continuous map $N:Cl \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^{\times}$. I don't understand, however, why $N$ is continuous. We define $N$ as $N(x):=x\cdot \alpha(t(x))$. Where $\alpha$ is the automorphism on the Clifford algebra induced by the map $v \mapsto -v$ on the underlying vector space and $t$ is the anti-automorphism that "switches the multiplication" in the algebra, i.e. $t(x\cdot y)=t(y)\cdot t(x)$.
Maybe this has an easy answer but I somehow feel very uncomfortable with the topology on $Cl$.
See f.e. Reprensentations of Compact Lie Groups by Bröcker and tom Dieck Chapter 1, Section 6 for precise definitions of $N, \alpha$ and $t$.

The definition of a topological vector space is such that scalar multiplication and addition are continuous operations on the vector space. The tensor product of vector spaces is also defined so that the tensor map is jointly continuous. Therefore the map $N$ is a composite of continuous maps, and so is continuous.

usually finite dim real or complex vector spaces are not assumed to be topological vector spaces, however they do have a unique topology compatible with the standard topology on the underlying field
